# Printing multiple statements after each other

Tags: python, console, spyder

When I execute the following code in Spyder:

```
print('a')
some_calculation
print('b')
print('c')
some_calculation
print('d')
print('e')
etc
```

where I use a function to look up items in a dictionary, it won't output all the strings to the console in Spyder. For example: it will print 'a' and 'b' and then nothing and after I hit ctrl+c to stop execution it will suddenly print the 'c' as well (it is then busy with the second calculation). When it's done all letter have been printed but they are not printed as the code is executed.

It seems that the console handles only one print statement correctly and while trying to display the next one it already starts on the calculation which freezes the output. Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: That is weird. Can you provide the actual code of the code base? The behavior you mentioned is not possible.

Comment: Console output that ends with a newline is supposed to appear immediately.  Perhaps Spyder is interfering with this?  Try putting `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print call.

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() did the trick. I noticed I was using print('a',end='') so the next output would be on the same line which probably cluttered the buffer.
Flushing the output does the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because print uses a buffer.
Since you seem to be using python 3, you can simply use `flush=True` in all your prints, and they will be printed straight away:

```
print('a', flush=True)
```